# Getting all shared values of two or more given values in one table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, join, table

I have a chat database where each user belongs to a chat; this relation is represented in the table "is_member(uid, cid)". Now, when creating a new chat, I want to check if there is not already a chat with exactly these users.
Here is my example table (users 1, 2, 3 and users 2, 3 have a chat together):

```
uid | cid
----|----
 1  |  1
 2  |  1
 3  |  1
 2  |  2
 3  |  2
```

Now how can I formulate my (My)SQL statement to get e.g. with the parameters uid=2 and uid=3 as output the following:

```
cid
---
 1
 2
```

… or with the parameters uid=1, uid=2 and uid=3:

```
cid
---
 1
```

Your help is much appreciated, I'm relatively new to SQL and I found nothing similar in this regard anywhere online. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for "(exact) relational division"

Comment: In your first example, if you query for uid=2 and uid=3 should both cid=1 and cid=2  be returned? Or just cid=2? You wording says "exactly" (so exact division) but if the expected is both cids, then you want plain relational division, not exact.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Have you considered a `UNIQUE` index on `(uid, cid)`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I looked into relational divison (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-division/) and it's not exactly what I'm looking for. For my example above (if I use the terms from the article), R(uid, cid) and S(cid), gives me a list of all users who are ever in all chats (2 and 3). But I have an input! I want to determine if a given "list" of users has a common chat (if every user from the list has at some point the same entry in cid).

Comment: Sounds like a "many-to-many" mapping table.  Here's the optimal schema: [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data and expected result I think you are looking for [MySQL HAVING](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) clause.

Your data:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
uid INT,
cid int  );

insert into test values (1,1), (2,1),(3,1),(2,2),(3,2);
```

First query.

> Now how can I formulate my (My)SQL statement to get e.g. with the
> parameters uid=2 and uid=3 as output the following:

```
select cid
from test
where uid in (2,3)
group by cid
having count(distinct uid) =2;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> cid
> 1
> 2
> ```

Second query.

> or with the parameters uid=1, uid=2 and uid=3:

```
select cid
from test
where uid in (1,2,3)
group by cid
having count(distinct uid) =3;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> cid
> 1
> ```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d98d0132ecea7b4730ab7b8e70813817

Note. The query is not dynamic so each time you change the where clause you need to change the `count(distinct uid)` to the number of values used on the where condition

Comment: Thank you very much, I was very close to this solution but I didn't knew about the "IN (1, 2, 3)"-thing! I chose in the meantime another approach where I format a broader SQL request with PHP.